# SQL Syntax to get AGPA

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Hi I have three tables as the following

[image]

I want to get the AGPA for the courses that the user passed

[image]

I used this SQL syntax

```
string queryString = 
     "select R.mark, c.NumberOfCredits 
      from Courses c, RegisteredIn R 
      where R.CourseId=c.id and R.StudentId=StudentId and 
            R.mark > 60 R.mark themark,c.NumberOfCredits credit 
            select (sum(themark*credit)/sum(credit))*0.04 AGPA    ";
```

and I did this to print out the results

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

        connection.Open();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();

        result = string.Empty;

        _AGPA = reader[3].ToString();

        result += string.Format("Your GPA : {0} </br>  ",_AGPA);

       Response.Write(result);
       reader.Close();
 }
```

Im pretty sure the SQL syntax is wrong
Im getting this error

[image]

kindly advise how to solve it and where I did a mistake.

Thank you

---

Update :

The Data Types are as the follwoing & Im using SQL Server database
[image]

---

Update 2 :

the StudentId is passed through the URL of the page as the following

```
http://localhost:3401/MobileWebWIthConnection/showagpa.aspx?StudentId=20111
```

and in the code I read it

```
string StudentId = Request.Params["StudentId"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query, it returnes AGPA for StudentId

```
select (sum(cast(R.mark as numeric) * cast(c.NumberOfCredits as numeric)) / sum(cast(c.NumberOfCredits as numeric)))*0.04 AGPA
from Courses c join RegisteredIn R 
on R.CourseId = c.id 
where R.StudentId = @studentId and R.mark > 60
```

After your line

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
```

add

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("studentId", YOUR_VARIABLE_FROM_URL);
```

Comment: I dont have c.StudentId , the StudentId is passed using the URL so instead I used (R.StudentId=StudentId) but still its not working its showing an error (Operand data type nchar is invalid for multiply operator.)

Comment: add data types of your db columns please, I'll see what columns shall I cast and please tell me what Database you use

Comment: and please I dont want the courseID or StudentID I need to get only the AGPA as " 3.33"

Comment: OK. I need data types and what Db

Comment: Kindly please check the question I updated it with the info you need

Comment: Try this: select (sum(cast(R.mark as int) * cast(c.NumberOfCredits as int)) / sum(cast(c.NumberOfCredits as int)))*0.04 AGPA
from Courses c, RegisteredIn R 
where R.CourseId = c.id and R.StudentId = StudentId and R.mark > 60
group by R.CourseId, R.StudentId

Comment: The Result Generated is 3.60 while the correct result is 3.15 ! why is that ?

((90*3 + 70*3 + 65*3 + 90*3)/12)*0.04 = 3.15

Comment: Dear I noticed that the SQL syntax is generating the GPA even without assigning the StudentId the result is always 3.60

Comment: For better answer I need access to Database =( I'll think about results

Comment: I just noticed, that my query had a mistake. Changed

Comment: Dear still wrong Im passing the StudentId value using the url, so in the URL if I dont write the studentid value the page should not compile , right ? with the SQL syntax you wrote its always showing the 3.32 even if I changed the StudentId , somthing wrong.

Comment: I created such tables in Oracle. Result of query is 3.15. How does you add studentid to query? Please write result query, which runs on sqlsrver

Comment: I added to the question how I read the StudentId and then add it to Query , Dear I noticed just now that when I add the student ID directly to the query as R.StudentId=20111 the result will show correctly. so how I can import the StudentId from the URL then ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: "and R.mark > 60 R.mark themark" are you missing an operator or something?

My guess is that you just need to remove the "R.mark the mark" after > 60